# Variable in switch, switch in loop, error in case 2

Tags: c#

Welcome, I've a problem with small funcion in switch.
My problem is "Use of unassigned local variable 'matrix'"
Here is a code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        char wyj = 'n';
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("1. add numbers into matrix \n2. show matrix \n3. end");
            int a;
            Console.Write("\nYour choice: ");
            a = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            switch (a)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("You choose: 1");

                    int element;
                    Console.Write("\nsize of matrix: ");
                    int matrixsize;
                    matrixsize = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    int[,] matrix = new int[matrixsize, matrixsize];

                    for (int i = 0; i <= matrixsize - 1; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j <= matrixsize - 1; j++)
                        {
                            Console.Write("element{0},{1} =", i + 1, j + 1);
                            element = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                            matrix[i, j] = element;
                        }
                    }
                    break;

                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("You choose 2");
                    foreach (int x in matrix)
                        Console.Write(x);
                        break;

                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("End the program? y- yes, n- no");
                    wyj = char.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                    break;

            }
        }
        while (wyj != 'y');
        Console.WriteLine("Koniec programu!");

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

What i need to do?

After Doc Brown answer, in case 2 nothing happens, the matrix is empty. 
I think the loop is the problem?

Comment: Code Review might be a better destination, but @DocBrown is right.

Comment: @itsbruce No, Code Review is not for code that doesn't work. Please don't send people to other sites if you don't know their rules.

Answer (score 2):

You should not assume that the user first enters 1, then 2, but expect that this might happen the other way round.

- the declaration `int[,] matrix` must be done *before* the switch statement, and you should set the variable to null there `int[,] matrix=null;`
- the initialization `matrix = new int[matrixsize, matrixsize]` can stay where it is, but
- in the `case 2` block, you have to check if matrix was initialized `if(matrix!=null) {/*...*/}`

Comment: Sorry Doc Brown, i didn't check after registration the domain.

Comment: After Doc Brown answer, in case 2 nothing happens, the matrix didn't show. maybe the loop is the problem?

Comment: @DominikMorawiec: PSE is not a "debugging service" (nor me). Now, where your code compiles, run your code under debugger control and work it out for yourself.

Comment: While moving the variable out of the switch will silence the error, I don't think it is enough to make the code actually do what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

You've made an assumption that the compiler can't verify--that you will always generate the matrix be forming viewing it. The compiler knows that this doesn't have to be the case in a switch statement, so it prevents you from using a variable which may never have been set (or in this case, even declared). If you want to keep this code, declare the variable outside of the case and initialize it to a new matrix. Then check in case two if it is safe to display.

Answer (score 0):

The `matrix` variable is local to the switch. The `case 2` uses the variable from `case 1`, because `case` does not introduce a scope, but it is *never* initialized there, because the initializer is not executed when doing `case 2`.

Moving the variable out of the `switch` will silence the error if you provide initializer, but it will still be a *new* variable in each iteration, so when you fill it in in `case 1`, it will come out empty when doing `case 2` in next iteration. You need to move the variable all the way out of the *loop* to have to values persist.

You still should not assume that user provides the inputs in correct order, so in the `case 2` you have to check that the matrix was already filled in.